# SQL query return duplicate with most recent date and more

Tags: mysql

I have a table: 'person' with many columns.
I need to return the full row of every entry that does not have a "duplicate" (defined below) along with the following: find the entries in that table that share the properties: first_name, last_name, and work_phone (these are duplicates for my purposes), and return only the entry with the most recent value in its date_modified field, ignoring the rest.

I feel like this is either a rather advanced query, or is deceptively simple. Either way I can't figure it out. I am using MySQL 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return only entries with the most recent value in its date_modified field, ignoring the rest:

```
SELECT p.* FROM
  ( SELECT max(date_modified) as most_recent_date 
    FROM person 
    GROUP BY first_name,last_name,work_phone ) p1
JOIN person p
ON p.date_modified = p1.most_recent_date
```

This will work well assuming date_modified is unique for every combination of fields we are grouping on. If not we have to join on a field that is unique, taking one arbitrary UUID (limit 1) satisfying most recent condition.

```
SELECT p.* FROM
  ( SELECT *,max(date_modified) as most_recent_date 
    FROM person 
    GROUP BY first_name,last_name,work_phone ) p1
JOIN person p
ON p.UUID =
  ( SELECT p_uniq.UUID 
    FROM person p_uniq
    WHERE p_uniq.first_name = p1.first_name
      AND p_uniq.last_name = p1.last_name
      AND p_uniq.work_phone = p1.work_phone
      AND p_uniq.date_modified = p1.most_recent_date
    LIMIT 1 )
```

And finally, return the full row of every entry that does not have a "duplicate":

```
SELECT * , count( * ) AS entries
FROM `person`
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, work_phone
HAVING entries =1
```

Comment: This query returns twice as many results as there are entries in the person table. It returns the duplicated rows like I asked, but it returns each one 10-12 times.

Comment: Is it possible that entries have exactly the same date_modified field?

Comment: What field makes a record unique then? How can you determine most recent if they can all be the same?

Comment: you have to join on this UUID then, hold on

Comment: Can you do this: `SELECT p.* FROM
  ( SELECT max(date_modified) as most_recent_date, id 
    FROM person 
    GROUP BY first_name,last_name,work_phone ) p1
JOIN person p
ON p.id = p1.id

Comment: You are selecting id which is not in group by list in subquery counting most recent date for different users, mysql is free to return any id from groupped by set, possibly not from the row that has max date in it.