# Query table with multiple "duplicates", getting the most recent

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table which stores predictions from a machine learning model.
This is a model that each hour ("predicted_at") predicts a value for the next 24 hours("predicted_for"). This means that the table have many different values for each "id" and "predicted_for".

Example of how the the table looks like for one ID and one predicted_for timestamp:

| value | id | predicted_at | predicted_for |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1825819489860161 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 16:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.14882256844401498 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 17:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-20 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.17357749613149909 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 17:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.20283864055714163 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 18:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.18582932551434195 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 19:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.18859835855398877 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 20:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.15969341546283378 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 21:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |
| 0.21578765348925422 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 22:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |

What I want to do is to query this data so that I get, for each ID, only one predicted value for each "predicted_for" timestemp, and I want this value to be "predicted_at" at "predicted_for - t(2) hours".

For the example, the result would give me the following table:

| value | id | predicted_at | predicted_for |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.15969341546283378 | 6970631400382957 | 2021-08-21 21:00:00 UTC | 2021-08-21 23:00:00 UTC |  |

I assume I would have some kind of group by and a having clause, but I have not figured out how to solve it.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  It is not clear from your explanation which row or values you want.  What is `t(2)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value(value) value, id, 
  any_value(predicted_at) predicted_at, predicted_for,   
from data t
where predicted_at = predicted_for - interval 2 hour
group by id, predicted_for
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do a query like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM
  ( SELECT max(predicted_at) as predicted_at_max 
    FROM youraboveschowedtable 
    GROUP BY id ) p1,
DATEADD(hour, -2, predicted_at) as predicted_minus2
JOIN youraboveschowedtable p
ON p.predicted_at = p1.predicted_at_max
```

litle altert Source = [SQL query return duplicate with most recent date and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824135/sql-query-return-duplicate-with-most-recent-date-and-more)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `YOURTABLE`
WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(predicted_for, predicted_at, HOUR) = 2
```

Note that it is not ensuring that you only have one record that matches the rule of having predicted_at preceding by 2 hours the value in predicted_for.
To also ensure this, the query should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `YOURTABLE` tab
WHERE predicted_at = (
    SELECT MAX(predicted_at)
    FROM `YOURTABLE` tab2
    WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(tab2.predicted_for, tab2.predicted_at, HOUR) = 2
    AND tab2.id = tab.id
)
```